# Should active directory module for powershell installed on a windows 7 machine to import it or can it be remotely imported from a Windows 2008 R2 DC?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

Currently i am working on taskpads for delegating some permissions to remote admins.I have following questions;

-> For Importing active directory module in powershell , shopuld it be locally installed or can it be imported remotely from a windows 2008 R2 DC?

-> For taskpads to work on remote workstations, should the administrative tools be installed on all the remote machines or is there a centralized way of maintaining them?

Please do let me know if anymore clarifications/questions regarding my efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import remote module in this way (remoting must be enabled on remote server):

Create a Powershell remote session to a server with the activedirectory module installed.

```
$Session = New-PSsession -Computername Server1
```

Use the newly created remote Powershell session to import the module to that session

```
Invoke-Command -Command {Import-Module ActiveDirectory} -Session $Session
```

Use that session with the modules to add the available commandlets from the activedirectory module to your local Powershell session adding a name prefix.

```
Import-PSSession -Session $Session -Module ActiveDirectory -Prefix RM
```

The code above enables the use of Active Directory commandlets on a computer that doesn’t have this module installed.

Use AD commandlets in the Powershell command shell with modified names based on the -Prefix set above:

`Get-RMAdUser`  instead of the standard `Get-ADUser`
`Get-RMAdComputer` instead of the standard `Get-ADComputer`

You can avoid  the `-Prefix RM` but it's handy for remember that are imported from remote.

For taskpad I'm pretty sure that must be present on each client installing RSAT with the ADUC mmc snap-in.